# Configure Joomla to send an email at login

Tags: plugin, user, joomla-3.5

Can someone let me know how to configure Joomla so that I get an email each time someone logs into my site.

At the moment, I get an email only when someone has registered. I'm running Joomla 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin in the Joomla Extensions Directory called "[Login Notify](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/login-notify)" that claims to do exactly this. I haven't used it myself, but according to the description:

> Login notify is a plugin that send email alert when any user log-in to
>   the system. You can even set the application for which you want to
>   make this plugin work, like only for admin section or only for site.
>   This plugin also allows you to set the usergroup(s) for which login
>   alerts are needed, suppose you do not want to get the alerts for super
>   users or administrator then this is completely possible with this
>   plugin. This plugin also facilitates you to send alert to the
>   logged-in user.

**How to install**
The plugin does not seem to follow Joomla standards when it comes to installation, so you'll have to do some extra work:

1. Download and unzip the file `login-notify.zip` to your computer.
2. Open the folder, and open the `source` folder inside.
3. Compress (zip) the contents of the `source` folder. The name of the zip-file does not matter.
4. Install the new zip file through your Joomla admin are (**Extensions -> Manage**.
5. Go to **Extensions -> Plugins** after installation and enable/configure the plugin.

Comment: Hi Johanpw, I'm going to try your suggestion. The other answers are a little too advanced for me to understand. However, if I don't have any luck I will revisit the other suggestions and hopefully someone will be able to talk me through it. I will let you know how I get on,

Comment: OK, Johanpw, and community. It looks like the 'Login Notify' is exactly what I need. Can someone give me quick guide on how to install plugins? I'm clearly a novice.

Comment: OK, so I have gone to 'Extension Manager' and attempted to install the 'login notify' files, but I keep on getting an error message each time I try to install the loginnotify.php file.

Comment: Hi, so I figured out how to install plugin. However, each time I attempt to install the plugin after uploading the file I get the message 'Unable to find install package'.. any thoughts?

Comment: @cpatte7372 the plugin does not follow Joomla standards for installation. Please see updated answer for installation instructions.

Comment: Hi Johanpw, this worked like a dream. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show me how to mark this question answered?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. You can [accept a question](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the grey check mark on the left hand side of the question (below the votes).

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no such built-in feature available. You can extend Joomla's functionality by writing a User plugin. When a user login to the site, Joomla will trigger the event onUserAfterLogin

https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterLogin

So you need to write your own User plugin to and implement onUserAfterLogin event to send emails. See below documentation to know how you can create a Joomla plugin.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

See below documentation to know how you can send emails from Joomla.

https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative, the firewall settings provided with [**Admin Tools by Akeeba**](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html), has option to send emails when a user has successfully logged in. It can even track unsuccessful attempts to login - and save the username and password that user used.

Just one note, because Admin tools comes in 2 editions (free and paid) I can't remember if the above features are included in the free edition.

Whatever the case, I would highly recommend Admin Tools pro, as it is a great utility that would also help protect and maintain your site. It's sort of a must-have extension for every Joomla.